# Linear systems and rational maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, surfaces, birational-geometry

I'm following Beauville's book on Complex Algebraic Surfaces.

If $D$ is a divisor on a surface $S$, we write $|D|$ for the set of all effective divisors linear equivalent to $D$ and we call it a complete linear system on a surface $S$. 
At page 14, Beauville says that $|D|$ can be identified with the projective space associated to the vector space $H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))$, so if i well understood, this means

$$|D|=\mathbb{P}H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D)).$$

But i think it should be $|D|=\mathbb{P} H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))^*.$

Could you help me in making this identification more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear system $|D|$ is the set of all effective divisors linearly equivalent to $D$. Consider the map $H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))\to|D|$ where $f\mapsto\mbox{div}(f)+D$ (here I am identifying $H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))$ with the vector space of all rational functions $f$ such that $\mbox{div}(f)+D\geq0$). This map is surjective, since if $E\in |D|$, then $E=\mbox{div}(f)+D$ for some $f$ ($E$ is linearly equivalent to $D$). If $\mbox{div}(f)+D=\mbox{div}(g)+D$, then $\mbox{div}(f/g)=0$, and so $f=\lambda g$ for some non-zero constant $\lambda$. Therefore the fibers are precisely the one dimensional linear subspaces of $H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))$, and so $|D|$ can be seen as the projectivization of $H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))$.

Comment: So there is no dual. Why in some text i find the dual space?

Comment: I think it is just a matter of terminology: the set of lines in a vector space $V$ is usually denoted $\mathbb P(V)$, but in the Algebraic Geometry world one should denote it $\mathbb P(V^\ast)$. I think idioteca was right in saying that $|D|=\mathbb P(H^0(\mathcal O_S(D))^\ast)$.

Comment: But i don't see why we should use the dual vector space now.

Comment: Because we talk about *lines* in $H^0(\mathcal O_S(D))$. But it not really important, over a field one can always identify a vector space with its dual and the problem disappears. However, strictly speaking, the set of lines in $V$ *is* $\mathbb P(V^\ast)$.

Comment: My understanding is that $\mathbb{P}(V^*)$ denotes the set of *hyperplanes* of $V$.

Comment: One way that the dual appears is when you look at the morphism defined by $|D|$. Assuming that $|D|$ is $n$-dimensional, the map $S\to\mathbb{P}^n$ defined by $|D|$ can be seen (without using coordinates) as the map $S\mapsto\mathbb{P}H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))^*$ where $p$ is mapped to the set of all sections that vanish at $p$.